# How to remove the trailing escape character in an argument?

Tags: macros

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{fp}

\def\newconst#1#2{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#1\endcsname{#2}%
    \pstVerb{/#1 \csname#1\endcsname\space def}%
}


\begin{document}

% I want to define a macro that can only be invoked as below
%\newconst\speed{3*10^8}

% rather than
\newconst{speed}{3*10^8}

\end{document}
```

If I do as follows, then I have to remove the trailing `\` in `#1` before appending it to `\pstVerb{/`. How to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{fp}

\def\newconst#1#2{%
    \FPeval#1{#2}%
    \pstVerb{/#1%<==== we must remove the trailing escape character \ in #1.
     #1\space def}%
}


\begin{document}

% I want to invoke
%\newconst\speed{3*10^8}

% instead of
\newconst{speed}{3*10^8}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difficult part is to strip the backslash for `\pstVerb`:

```
\def\newconst#1#2{%
    \FPeval#1{#2}%
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\pstVerb{/\stripbs#1 #1\noexpand\space def}}\x
}
\makeatletter
\def\stripbs{\expandafter\@gobble\string}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\def\newconstb#1{%
  {\escapechar-1
   \xdef\tmp{\noexpand\newconst{\string#1}}}\tmp}
```

Produces a string of the command name with no backslash then calls the original macro/.

Comment: `\newconstb` should take 2 arguments. Unfortunately, it does not work even with 2 arguments. I have no idea why.

Comment: No It would work as shown `\newconstb\foo{abd}` would be the same as `\newconst{foo}{abc}` as long as you don't need it in an expansion only context like \erite or \special. There is no need (and it is inefficient) to define a macro with an argument just to pass it on at the end of its expansion.