# Use a macro to define a \NewDocumentCommand macro without backslash

Tags: macros, etoolbox, xparse

Or as, Werner simplified it: "*How to define a command without backslash in xparse*".

---

#### Background:

I am trying to set up a macro to define a macro for me (which will also do some other things which are not essential in the MWE below).

The first version below set up the macro by passing in `\NumericalToNumber` as `#1`. Note the `\` in the name.

```
\DefineMacro{\NumericalToNumber}{%
    {one}{1}%
    {two}{2}%
    {three}{3}% 
    {four}{4}% 
}%
```

This does exactly what I desire.

[image]

However to perform the "other things" I need done in `\DefineMacro`, I need to have the macro name available without the backslash. So, I though it would be easy to change the call to not have `\` in the name, and use `csuse{}` from the `etoolbox` to generate the name (as opposed to the usual `\expandafter\csname...\endcsname`):

```
\DefineMacro{NumericalToNumber}{%
    {one}{1}%
    {two}{2}%
    {three}{3}% 
    {four}{4}% 
}%
```

But I can't seem to get this version to work.

I also tried to stick with the first version and adapt the solution from [How to remove the trailing escape character in an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64377/how-to-remove-the-trailing-escape-character-in-an-argument) but that did not work for me. Basically the code needed for the "other things" is already functional so would prefer to get the second version to work.

---

### Code: Works: Use `\` in `\DefineMacro`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
    
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineMacro}{m m}{%
    % #1 = command name to be defined (WITH backslash).
    % #2 = pairs of {<property name>}{<propery value} (same as what \ItStrEqCase accepts)
    \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{s O{UNKNOWN}}{%
        \IfStrEqCase{##2}{%
            #2% 
        }[\fbox{Unknown property name='##2' in \string#1.}]%
    }%
}%

\DefineMacro{\NumericalToNumber}{%
    {one}{1}%
    {two}{2}%
    {three}{3}% 
    {four}{4}% 
}%

\begin{document}
\NumericalToNumber[two]

\NumericalToNumber[four]

\NumericalToNumber[ten]
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Does NOT work without `\` in `\DefineMacro`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
    
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineMacro}{m m}{%
    % #1 = command name to be defined (withOUT backslash).
    % #2 = pairs of {<property name>}{<propery value} (same as what \ItStrEqCase accepts)
    \NewDocumentCommand{\csuse{#1}}{s O{UNKNOWN}}{% <---- Use of \csuse here
        \IfStrEqCase{##2}{%
            #2% 
        }[\fbox{Unknown property name='##2' in \string#1.}]%
    }%
}%

\DefineMacro{NumericalToNumber}{% <--- No backslash here in #1.
    {one}{1}%
    {two}{2}%
    {three}{3}% 
    {four}{4}% 
}%

\begin{document}
\NumericalToNumber[two]

\NumericalToNumber[four]

\NumericalToNumber[ten]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect your problem would be solved by using `expl3` when using `xparse`, but to be perfectly honest, I don't fully understand the problem.  Feel free to chalk that up to my lack of sleep, though :)  The same functionality could easily be implemented using a `prop` structure.

Comment: What you *could* do is use some sort of helper macro to turn that first argument into a cs for the 'main' macro (the one that's working right now).  That's probably the most unobtrusive solution sans the actual fix.

Comment: I imagine you could heavily simply this question: "How to define a command without backslash in `xparse`" (no `xstring`, no options). Maybe?

Comment: I assume that `\SSErrorBox` is not really important for the question?

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/issues/179 to me: the team are aware of the question but are not really sure what the best solution is at present. Conceptually, `\NewDocumentCommand` goes with commands that are 'fixed' rather than 'dynamic', _i.e._ they might be expected to all be listed individually, and one concept for LaTeX3 in general is 'self-documenting code'. There is an issue with some areas where long lists of similar commands are to be expected, and we still haven;t round the ideal solution.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Oppss, have removed that irrelevant piece of the code.  Thanks.

Comment: @JosephWright: The reason I am using `xparse` is that `xparse` makes it really easy to provide a `*` variant of the macro (not illustrated in this MWE). Otherwise I would have used `\newcommand`.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks. Have updated the question to reflect your concise summary.

Comment: @PeterGrill: [This is what I meant by making your problem more concise](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sMx3d.png). The main inquiry here is to provide the means to generate a macro without passing it as a control sequence (with a ``\``).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure this is what is expected, but

```
\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand{\csname#1\endcsname}
```

does not work, but

```
\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname#1\endcsname
```

indeed does. The first way tries to treat the  name of the macro (NumericalToNumber) as the argument type list, leading to an error about an unknown 'N' argument type.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\DefineMacro}{mm}{%
  % #1 = command name to be defined (withOUT backslash).
  % #2 = pairs of {<property name>}{<propery value} (same as what \ItStrEqCase accepts)
  \expandafter\DeclareDocumentCommand\csname#1\endcsname{s O{UNKNOWN}}{%
    \IfStrEqCase{##2}{%
      #2% 
        }[\fbox{Unknown property name='##2' in \string#1.}]%
      }%
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\OtherDefineMacro}{mm}{%
  % #1 = command name to be defined (withOUT backslash).
  % #2 = pairs of {<property name>}{<propery value} (same as what \ItStrEqCase accepts)
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname#1\endcsname{s O{UNKNOWN}}{%
    \IfStrEqCase{##2}{%
      #2% 
        }[\fbox{Unknown property name='##2' in \string#1.}]%
      }%
}


\DefineMacro{NumericalToNumber}{% <--- No backslash here in #1.
    {one}{1}%
    {two}{2}%
    {three}{3}% 
    {four}{4}% 
}%

\OtherDefineMacro{OtherNumericalToNumber}{% <--- No backslash here in #1.
    {one}{1}%
    {two}{2}%
    {three}{3}% 
    {four}{4}% 
}%


\begin{document}
\NumericalToNumber[two]

\NumericalToNumber[four]

\OtherNumericalToNumber[eight]

\NumericalToNumber[ten]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I provided a version with `\DeclareDocumentCommand` too.

Comment: You need to »step over« the brace: `\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}` or leave the braces away: `\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname#1\endcsname`

Comment: @cgnieder: Thanks, but that's basically what I have done in my 'without braces' solution (if it's a solution at all)

Comment: You say `\expandafter\NewDocumentName{\csname#1\endcsname}` doesn't work without explanation which is why I tried to offer one :). BTW: is `\NewDocumentName` a typo? (Other than that I haven't looked at the question and answer – I'm at work right now...)

Comment: Of course the first version doesn't work: you're trying to expand `{`.

Comment: @egreg: Yes. And I thought that was the way the OP was doing it. Perhaps I have misinterpreted the statements

Answer (score 10):

It's a very common problem: you have to provide a symbolic token (the macro name) before `\NewDocumentCommand` starts its job:

```
\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname ...\endcsname
```

is the solution; the more complicated

```
\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\expandafter{\csname ...\endcsname}
```

works as well.

There is a slicker way, that avoids doing `\expandafter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\SSErrorBox}[1]{\fbox{#1}}
\newcommand{\command}[1]{\texttt{#1}}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineMacro}{m m}
 {
  % #1 = command name to be defined (without backslash).
  % #2 = pairs of {<property name>}{<property value>}
  \grill_define_macro:cn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \grill_define_macro:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{s O{UNKNOWN}}
   {
    \str_case:nnF { ##2 } { #2 }
     { \SSErrorBox{Unknown~property~name="##2"~in~"\command{\string#1}".} }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \grill_define_macro:Nn { c }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DefineMacro{NumericalToNumber}{% <--- No backslash here in #1.
  {one}{1}
  {two}{2}
  {three}{3} 
  {four}{4}
}

\begin{document}

X\NumericalToNumber[two]X

X\NumericalToNumber[four]X

X\NumericalToNumber[ten]X

\end{document}
```

The macro `\DefineMacro` simply passes control to `\grill_define_macro:cn`. We then define `\grill_define_macro:Nn`; according to the conventions in `expl3`, this function expects two arguments: an unbraced single token (`N`) and a normally braced argument (`n`).

Argument `#1` is the macro to define with `\NewDocumentCommand`, `#2` is the list of pairs `{<key>}{<value>}`. Instead of `\IfStrEqCase` we can use `\str_case:nnF`, that is called as

```
\str_case:nnF
 { ##2 } % the second argument to the macro
 { #2 }  % the list of properties
 { ... } % what to do when there's no match
```

Of course you're free to use `\IfStrEqCase`, if you prefer, just remember that in the programming environment `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`\ExplSyntaxOff` spaces are ignored and wanted spaces have to be supplied as `~`.

Finally, the variant `\grill_define_macro:cn` is defined; the magic happens here: `c` means that the argument must be braced and a symbolic token will be built from it *before* `\grill_define_macro:Nn` is executed.

[image]

I used some X's in order to show that no spurious space crept in.

---

Here is the definition of `\NewDocumentCommand` in `xparse.sty`:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \NewDocumentCommand #1#2#3
  {
    \cs_if_exist:NTF #1
      {
        \__msg_kernel_error:nnx { xparse } { command-already-defined }
          { \token_to_str:N #1 }
      }
      { \__xparse_declare_cmd:Nnn #1 {#2} {#3} }
  }
```

If this had been

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xparse_new_document_command:Nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \cs_if_exist:NTF #1
      {
        \__msg_kernel_error:nnx { xparse } { command-already-defined }
          { \token_to_str:N #1 }
      }
      { \__xparse_declare_cmd:Nnn #1 {#2} {#3} }
  }
\cs_set_eq:NN \NewDocumentCommand \xparse_new_document_command:Nnn
```

you could simply say, in your document,

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xparse_new_document_command:Nnn { c }
\cs_set_eq:NN \NewDocumentCommandName \xparse_new_document_command:cnn
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and you could use `\NewDocumentCommandName{<name>}{<args>}{<code>}` where `<name>` is the macro name without the backslash.

There may be good reasons for not doing this in the package.

You can do it yourself, however:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \grill_new_document_command:Nnn \NewDocumentCommand
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \grill_new_document_command:Nnn { c }
\cs_set_eq:NN \NewDocumentCommandName \grill_new_document_command:cnn
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

However, I'd prefer the strategy outlined above.

Comment: Something like `\NewDocumentCommand \NewDocumentCommandName { } { \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand }` is what I would do. Isn't that a good approach?

Comment: @Manuel It's essentially the same as using `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`

Answer (score 1):

I thought that the *standard* approach, when `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` is not available (like this case), was using `\exp_args:??`. In this case

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \DefineMacro { }
  { \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Or, for one it's not necessary `\ExplSyntax..`

```
\NewDocumentCommand\DefineMacro{}
  {\csname exp_args:Nc\endcsname\NewDocumentCommand}
 %{\csuse{exp_args:Nc}\NewDocumentCommand}
```