# How to define a newcommand that expands into another newcommand

Tags: macros

I'm not sure exactly what terminology to use to ask this question.

What I want to do is define a command pluralize such that I can do this:

```
\newcommand{\individual}{individual\xspace}
\pluralize{\individual}

the \individual with the \individuals
```

and then get

```
the individual with the individuals
```

---

The reason I want to do this is because I might change terminology like:

```
\newcommand{\individual}{name\xspace}
\pluralize{\individual}

the \individual with the \individuals
```

and then get

```
the name with the names
```

---

Currently what I'm doing is explicitly writing out the plural version of each command like:

```
\newcommand{\individual}{individual\xspace}
\newcommand{\individuals}{\individual{}s\xspace}
```

But it seems like I should be able to turn this into a macro for simple pluralizations.

I have tried three things so far that do not work. First I tried what I thought may work:

```
\newcommand{\pluralize}[1]{\newcommand{\#1}{\#1{}s\xspace}
```

Then I looked online. I tried following the guidelines in 
[Defining a newcommand, with variable name, inside another newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28704/defining-a-newcommand-with-variable-name-inside-another-newcommand)
I came up with

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pluralize}[1]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1s\endcsname{#1{}s\xspace}%
}
\makeatother
```

and

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pluralize}[1]{%
    \@namedef{#1s}{\\#1s\xspace}
}
\makeatother
\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1s\endcsname{#1{}s}%
```

but I either get a compile error, or an error if I use the macro. I'm not really  sure what the @namedef, \expandafter, or \csname commands do either.

---

How can I correctly define the pluralize command?

Answer (score 11):

I'd change the approach:

```
\newcommand{\makename}[3][s]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname{#3\xspace}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #2s\endcsname{#3#1\xspace}%
}

\makename{individual}{name}
\makename[es]{veggie}{potato}
```

In the document you can do

```
The \individual eats \veggie, while \individuals eat \veggies.
```

that will print

> The name eats potato, while names eat potatoes.

Note. In general I recommend against using `\xspace`; I do also in this case.

Comment: With three arguments, the first one optional, I think your argument numbers in the newcommand are incorrect. The first would be \csname #2\endcsname{#3}, the plural one would be \csname #2s\endcsname{#3#1}, right?

Comment: @AndrewCashner Right!

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to achieve it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace,xparse}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64380/5764
\makeatletter
\def\stripbs{\expandafter\@gobble\string}

\NewDocumentCommand{\createplural}{m m O{s}}{%
  \newcommand{#1}{#2\xspace}%
  \@namedef{\stripbs#1#3}{#2#3\xspace}%
}
\makeatother

\createplural{\individual}{name}%[s]

\begin{document}

The \individual with the \individuals.

\end{document}
```

`\pluralize{<csname>}{<name>}[<plural>]` provides an optional "`<plural>`" as the last argument.

While using [`xspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) is sometimes [beneficial](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/5764), it also has its [drawbacks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/5764).