# command to create commands

Tags: macros

Is it possible to make a command that create commands??

Something like:

```
\newcommand{apprentice}[4][forestgreen]{ %
\newcommand{#2}{ \color{#1} Lærling #3}%
 \newcommand{a#2}{\color{#1} #4}%
}
```

that creates 2 new commands `\#2` and `\a#2` defined as shown above.

this would just be faster than doing the above 8+ times

Comment: `\expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname{\color{#1}...}` etc.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259287/how-to-define-a-newcommand-that-expands-into-another-newcommand, so it's most likely a duplicate, but I won't use the [macro] - gold - badge hammer right now to close this question

Comment: Christian Hupfer You are right it is a duplicate, that thread did not come up when i wrote command to make commands in the `ask a question` field.

Comment: You can do so XD, still can't get the colors working thou XD, but just close it

Comment: got it working, just forgot to put in the package that gives me forestgreen XD, stupid mistake. Thanks for the help